# VS 2008 c# pre-build events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I need to ecexute a .exe app prior to my website being built.

Am I able to execute command shell using pre-build events?

Sp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do whatever you want before anything else happens.

Comment: ive tried to execut as i would using cmd but it fails everytime, do u have an example?

Comment: So I created a new website project and couldn't see any way to run a pre-build event from that. I added a new "empty" project to the solution and could quite happily run "dir" as a pre-build event. What error are you seeing?

Comment: But what does it say when you tell it to do that? Does it say it can't find it? Does it say there was any problem?

Comment: Error 1 The command ""c:\runthis.exe"" exited with code 9009.

Comment: If you open up a regular cmd prompt and paste in exactly the same command line does it work? It sounds like it's a) not finding the exe, b) not finding a DLL the exe needs to run. Is that the actual command line your using? There's not a path with spaces in that might be causing trouble?